# PHP mail : can't read message body on iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, email

I made a site for a friend, but I encounter a strange problem : the site provides a form where the user can send him a mail.

The mail is OK on desktop, but when he reads it on his iPhone 4 (iOs 7), the body of the message is empty.

Here is the code of the PHP script that make and send the email :

```
<?php
$mail = 'mail@example.fr'; 
if (filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
{
    $passage_ligne = "\r\n";
}
else
{
    $passage_ligne = "\n";
}

$message_txt = $_POST['question'];
$emetteur = 'test@test.com';

$boundary = "-----=".md5(rand());



$sujet = 'The message :';
$nom = $_POST['nom'];
$demande = $_POST['demande'];
$niveau = $_POST['niveau'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];

$header = "From: ".$emetteur.$passage_ligne;
$header.= "Reply-to: ".$emetteur.$passage_ligne;
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$passage_ligne;
$header.= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;".$passage_ligne." boundary=\"$boundary\"".$passage_ligne;

$message = $passage_ligne."--".$boundary.$passage_ligne;

$message.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"".$passage_ligne;
$message.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$passage_ligne;
$message.= $passage_ligne.'Une personne a demandé à ce que tu le rappelles :'.$nom.$passage_ligne;
$message.= $passage_ligne.'Il veut : '.$demande.' Son niveau est : '.$niveau.$passage_ligne;
$message.= $passage_ligne.'Il a un message : '.$message_txt.$passage_ligne;
$message.= $passage_ligne.'Voici son num pour le rappeler : '.$tel.$passage_ligne;

$message.= $passage_ligne."--".$boundary.$passage_ligne;




if(mail($mail,$sujet,$message,$header))
echo "Votre message a bien &eacute;t&eacute; envoy&eacute; !";
else 
echo "Votre message n'a pas pu &eacirc;tre envoy&eacute;.";

?>
```

Comment: It happens with my nexus 5 most of the times. Refreshing the email usually downloads the body and solves the problem. May be this works for you.

Comment: just for test. send message body without special french letters.

Comment: I'll try that. Should I encore $message to UTF8 ?